# Have a problem with rendering same widget in a if/else statement inside the builder function of FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

Maybe I'm not correctly understanding how widget rebuild works but for example in this chunk of code. because the initial value is false then the flow goes for the *else* block and create the MultiProvider widget in that block, all is working fine. Then after the future completes it returns true so it goes for the *if* block but the MultiProvider is not recreated again and the properties I put does not reflect on the nested widgets like the Stream I am attaching in providers argument. Also I debugged with breakpoints and in effect, the program does not call the `someProviderOfStream.streamWithAcceptedPermissions()` function. So my question is how actually this works, and how can I recreate the MultiProvider Object.

```
return FutureBuilder(
    initialData: false,
    future: someObj.fetchHasPermission(), // true or false
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('no data');
      bool hasPermission = snapshot.data;
      if (hasPermission) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            StreamProvider<String>(builder: (context) => someProviderOfStream.streamWithAcceptedPermissions()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeProvider>.value(value: _someProvider),
          ],
          child: SomeWidget()
        );
      } else {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            StreamProvider<String>(builder: (context) => someProviderOfStream.emptyStream()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeProvider>.value(value: _someProvider),
          ],
          child: SomeWidget()
        );
      }
    }
  );
```

Also I tested with returning a different Widget in the *else* block for example a Text() widget and the program works correctly. It seems like Flutter optimizes the build function and avoid to recreate Same-Type Widgets before created, but I'm not sure.

```
return FutureBuilder(
    initialData: false,
    future: someObj.fetchHasPermission(), // true or false
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('no data');
      bool hasPermission = snapshot.data;
      if (hasPermission) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            StreamProvider<String>(builder: (context) => someProviderOfStream.streamWithAcceptedPermissions()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeProvider>.value(value: _someProvider),
          ],
          child: SomeWidget()
        );
      } else {
        return Text('has no Permission');
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the use of keys on widgets. With this, flutter knows it should recreate the widget with the changes made on `MultiProvider` object. Thanks to [rrousselGit](https://github.com/rrousselGit) to remember me the key property of widgets.